# k3s install on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi4, k3s

I am currently trying installing k3s into my Raspberry Pi 4. I added ***cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory*** inside the file cmdline.txt and reboot the pi. After that I still get an error information as following:

> `[INFO]  Finding release for channel stable [INFO]  Using v1.25.3+k3s1 as release [INFO]  Downloading hash https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.25.3+k3s1/sha256sum-arm64.txt [INFO]  Downloading binary https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/download/v1.25.3+k3s1/k3s-arm64 [INFO]  Verifying binary download [INFO]  Installing k3s to /usr/local/bin/k3s [INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/kubectl symlink to k3s [INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/crictl symlink to k3s [INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/ctr symlink to k3s [INFO]  Creating killall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh [INFO]  Creating uninstall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-uninstall.sh [INFO]  env: Creating environment file /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service.env [INFO]  systemd: Creating service file /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service [INFO]  Failed to find memory cgroup, you may need to add "cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory" to your linux cmdline (/boot/cmdline.txt on a Raspberry Pi) [INFO]  systemd: Enabling k3s unit Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/k3s.service → /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service. [INFO]  systemd: Starting k3s Job for k3s.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status k3s.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

What could possiblly go wrong here?

I have tried many times and failed again and again.

Comment: What you did should have worked: could you share/check back on your cmdline.txt?!

Comment: I find out that actually "cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory" should be added into the end of the first line instead of being added at the new line.

Comment: Indeed, nailed it: feel free to post this as an answer, rather than a comment!